# %g gives Exponential Form of Value in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, precision

**My Requirement**

There is one label having Price Value (Float Value)

If it is -> Then It should be

1232.200 -> 1232.2

1232.243 -> 1232.243

1232.00 -> 1232

**What I had Done till Now**

1) Used %.2f

```
lblPrice.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",myValue];
```

But it always give 2 digits after points like `1232.20`, `1232.24`, `1232.00` Respectively...

2) So then I change `%.2f` to `%g`

```
lblPrice.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",myValue];
```

That Gives Perfect Value for all The above requirement, But when the value exceeds to some level , It is converted to exponential form like this..

If myValue is `1189243.609` then It results in `1.18924e+06`
Which I don't want..

Any Solution for this???
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Have you tried using ceilf() in case you want to round up float values?

Comment: I dont want to round up float value, If there is precision Then there should be float ... @Rishab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just test the following code and that work as per your requirement hope that help:

```
NSNumberFormatter *NumberFormate = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[NumberFormate setRoundingIncrement:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.001]];
[NumberFormate setMaximumFractionDigits:4];
[NumberFormate setMinimumFractionDigits:0];

NSLog(@"232.200 IS %@", [NumberFormate stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1232.200]]);
NSLog(@"1232.243 IS %@", [NumberFormate stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1232.243]]);
NSLog(@"1232.00 IS %@", [NumberFormate stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1232.00]]);
```

It's output is :

[image]

**UPDATE:**

For your 0.50 if you want to output like 0.5 then just add one more line in your existing code like following.

```
[NumberFormate setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
```

Comment: I found the same solution... & It worked.. Thanks Anyway ... :)

Comment: This solution gives me .5 for 0.50 value... How to get 0.5 instead of .5? @Nitin Gohel

Comment: @Sam check updated answer you need to add `[NumberFormate setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];`

Answer (score 1):

You can try both of this one by one

```
lblPrice.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%qi", myValue];
```

or

```
lblPrice.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", myValue];
```

Or View the following link

> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html